# C++20 concept for complex floating point types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to learn concepts in C++20 and I have a class that represents a data sample. I want to restrict this class to accept only floating point types, or complex floating point types but I can't seem to figure out how to handle complex values with concepts.

Without concepts this is simple, but it allows way too many other data types that I don't want to allow.

Example without concepts:

```
template <typename T>
class Sample
{
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    // This compiles
    Sample<double> s1;
    Sample<complex<double>> s2;

    // This also compiles (but I don't want it to!)
    Sample<int> s3;
    // This compiles as well (again, I don't want it to!)
    Sample<complex<int>> s4;
}
```

With concepts I can easily restrict it to just take floating point values but then it doesn't work with complex values.

```
template<floating_point T>
class Sample
{
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    // This compiles
    Sample<double> s1;
    Sample<float> s2;

    // This does NOT compile (but I do want it to!)
    Sample<complex<double>> s3;
}
```

How can I create a concept to restrict the template to work with both real and complex floating point values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one solution that uses a partial specialization to check if `T` is a specialization of `std::complex` for floating point types:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

template <std::floating_point T>
struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

With this, you can write the concept:

```
template <typename T>
concept complex = std::floating_point<T> || is_complex<T>::value;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E6xo3o).

Comment: @cigien that's ALMOST exactly what I'm looking for, but this will also allow `Sample<complex<int>>` when I only want it to work for complex floating point numbers.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 I see. Fixed, you just have to constrain the specialization of `is_complex` to floating point types :) Also, in the future, it'd be nice if you added that test to the question (like I did in the demo).

Comment: @tjwrona1992 No problem :) By the way, you might be interested to know that an instantiation like `complex<int>` is unspecified in c++ anyway, so you probably shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's code using a helper type trait class with partial specialization, to determine if a type is complex with floating point coordinates.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <complex>

template <typename T>
struct is_complex_floating_point : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_complex_floating_point<std::complex<T>>
    : public std::bool_constant<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>
{};

template <typename T>
concept real_or_complex_floating_point =
    std::floating_point<T> || 
    is_complex_floating_point<std::remove_const_t<T>>::value;

template<real_or_complex_floating_point T>
class Sample
{
    // ...
};
```

I used the `remove_const_t` because `std::floating_point` is satisfied by `const float`, etc., meaning your existing `Sample` (with constrained parameter) would allow `Sample<const double>`, etc. So the concept is defined to accept `const std::complex<T>`, making `Sample<const std::complex<double>>` etc. work. If that shouldn't be considered valid, you can remove the `remove_const_t` part and possibly consider also restricting your template to forbid cv-qualified types.

[As @cigien noticed in [their solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287611), the partial specialization of `is_complex_floating_point` is simpler to write using the `std::floating_point` concept. An exercise for the reader. ;) ]

Answer (score 1):

The solution presented here is not essentially different from, or in any sense better than the [one posted by cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287611). The goal is to demonstrate an alternative technique using a SFINAE-like property of the *concept_id*.

A concept variable template is syntactically a regular implicitly `inline constexpr bool` template variable with a *constraint-expression* as its value. The semantic deviation from the regular SFINAE rule is that a substitution failure results in the concept variable evaluated to `false` (N4868 §7.5.7.1(6)), as opposed to being considered non-viable in the SFINAE case:

> The substitution of template arguments into a *requires-expression* may result in the formation of invalid types or expressions in its requirements or the violation of the semantic constraints of those requirements. [This is how SFINAE works. -kkm] In such cases, the *requires-expression* evaluates to `false`; it does not cause the program to be ill-formed.

With this in mind, a complex float concept may be defined as

```cpp
template <typename T, typename F = T::value_type>
concept Complex = (std::is_floating_point_v<F> &&
                   std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>, std::complex<F>>);
```

The template argument `F` is substituted with the base type of `std::complex<F>`, exposed via that template's member type alias `value_type`. The concept expression asserts that `F` is indeed a floating point type, and that the `T` itself is a specialization of `std::complex<F>` up to CV-qualification.

Another useful restriction is defined in (§13.7.9(5) Note 1):

> ... A concept cannot be explicitly instantiated, explicitly specialized, or partially specialized.

This means that in practice the template argument `F` is a constant, preventing any "creative use" in case such a concept is defined in a general-purpose library. This is in contrast to a regular inline template variable, where the parameter `F` might be explicitly specified by the user of the template.

The `RealOrComplex` concept is defined trivially as

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept RealOrComplex = std::is_floating_point_v<T> || Complex<T>;
```

---

Below is a full working example, compiled (or failing to, if you wish, depending on the definition of `TRY_COMPILING_THIS`) with GCC, Clang and MSVC.

```cpp
#define _SILENCE_NONFLOATING_COMPLEX_DEPRECATION_WARNING 1  // Otherwise clang complains a deluge.

#include <complex>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename F = T::value_type>
concept Complex = (std::is_floating_point_v<F> &&
                   std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>, std::complex<F>>);
template <typename T>
concept RealOrComplex = std::is_floating_point_v<T> || Complex<T>;

template <RealOrComplex T>
class Sample {
 public:
  constexpr explicit Sample(T value) noexcept : _value(value) {}

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sample& sample) {
    return os << sample._value, os;
  }

 private:
  T _value;
};

int main() {
  using std::complex;
  using namespace std::complex_literals;

  std::cout
    << "CTAD:\n"
    << "  R(32)    : " << Sample{3.14f} << "\n"
    << "  R(64)    : " << Sample{3.14} << "\n"
    << "  C(32,32) : " << Sample{3.0f + 0.14if} << "\n"
    << "  C(64,64) : " << Sample{0.14 + 3.0i} << "\n\n";

  std::cout
    << "Explicit:\n"
    << "  R(32)    : " << Sample<float>{3.14f} << "\n"
    << "  R(64)    : " << Sample<double>{3.14} << "\n"
    << "  C(32,32) : " << Sample<complex<float>>{3.0f + 0.14if} << "\n"
    << "  C(64,64) : " << Sample<complex<double>>{0.14 + 3.0i} << "\n";

#define TRY_COMPILING_THIS 0
#if TRY_COMPILING_THIS
  // MSVC: no matching function for call to 'Sample(int)'
  // clang: constraints not satisfied for class template 'Sample' [with T = int]
  Sample{1};
  Sample<int>{1};

  //  There is no suffix for an `int` in `complex_literals`, so that braces must
  //  be doubled: the inner pair CTAD-constructs a `complex<int>`, the outer is
  //  the usual uniform initialization syntax. See the last line of the three
  //  where the `complex<int>` argument to `Sample.ctor` is constructed explicitly.
  //  All three definitions are equivalent up to CTAD vs. explicit specialization.
  Sample{{1, 1}};
  Sample<complex<int>>{{1, 1}};
  Sample<complex<int>>{complex<int>{1, 1}};
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little experimentation shows that you can do this:

```
template <class T>
concept is_floating_point_or_complex = std::is_floating_point_v<T> || std::is_same_v <T, std::complex <double>>;

template<is_floating_point_or_complex T>
class Sample
{
    // ...
};
```

But it's not obvious how to avoid specialising `std::complex` in `is_floating_point_or_complex` (if indeed you want to).

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DTyOlBJJuRD70XQR)

Comment: This solution is also close, but does not work for `Sample<complex<float>>`

Comment: Well, you can add another condition to the concept for that: `template <class T>
concept is_floating_point_or_complex = std::is_floating_point_v<T> || std::is_same_v <T, std::complex <double>> || std::is_same_v <T, std::complex <float>>;`